# How to get latest artifacts or files from Jenkins to local machine

Tags: rest, jenkins, curl, jenkins-cli, jenkins-api

I need to download using Jenkins cli or Jenkins api or any other rest API. I need to download artifact to local machine. How is this possible can any one explain

Comment: Please elaborate. What artifacts? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Jenkins is not an artifact repository/manager.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to download the artifact from a particular job at your local system you can use curl or wget command to download it.

eg. `curl -u Jenkins_User:Jenkins_Password https://jenkinsurl/artifactpath/file.zip --output "localfilename.zip"`